# minimum and argmin in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array I need to find the minimum and the position of the minimum. 
This can be done using

```
>>> current_cost
array([ 2.54802261,  2.98627555,  0.23873749,  1.82511195,  1.35469083])
>>> current_cost.min()
0.23873748917821858
>>> current_cost.argmin()
2
```

This solutions is not very efficient because it needs to scan the list two times. 
Is there a way to obtain minimum and agrmin at the same time?

Comment: If you're doing this in an inner loop, you probably should use a heap or tree.

Comment: I am using it in a loop.  The values of the vector current cost change every iteration

Comment: There really should be a function "np.arg**and**min(...)"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
min_pos = current_cost.argmin()
min_val = current_cost[min_pos]
```

Comment: How would this work when you're taking the argmin of a multi-dimensional array along one axis? `min_pos = a.argmin(axis=1)`, `min_vals=?`

Comment: @MartinWiebusch `min_val = current_cost[np.arange(current_cost.shape[0]), min_pos]` works; not sure if there's anything nicer.

Comment: There is np.take_along_axis ( https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html )